# Trigger scroll event when changing focused element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, html-table

I have an html table where I have enabled the keyboard navigation:
Each td in the table has tabIndex="1", I have added the handler for each td's onkeydown event. In the handler I calculate the keydowned's td row and column number, calculate the new row/column numbers according to which arrow key is pressed, and then do the focus(). Here's the function:

```
function pivotKeyDown(event, element) {
    var elementToSelect = event.srcElement ? event.srcElement : (event.target ? event.target : event.toElement);
    var row, col, t = $(elementToSelect);
    currentCol = t.index();
    currentRow = t.closest('tr').index();

    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            t.closest('table').find('tr:nth-child(' + (currentRow + 1) + ')').find('td:nth-child(' + (currentCol) + ')').focus();
            break;
        case 38:
            t.closest('table').find('tr:nth-child(' + (currentRow) + ')').find('td:nth-child(' + (currentCol + 1) + ')').focus();
            break;
        case 39:
            t.closest('table').find('tr:nth-child(' + (currentRow + 1) + ')').find('td:nth-child(' + (currentCol + 2) + ')').focus();
            break;
        case 40:
            t.closest('table').find('tr:nth-child(' + (currentRow + 2) + ')').find('td:nth-child(' + (currentCol + 1) + ')').focus();
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The table usually is too big to be shown on the page, so it's placed inside a div that displays scrollbars if the table is too big.

Now, the problem is that when I navigate using the keys, the focused cell changes, and when I go over the viewport borders, it moves the table inside the div (so that the new selected cell is visible), but it doesn't trigger the scroll event, not does it change the scrollbars, so that even if the bottom right cell in the table is selected, the scrollbars positions are still as if it's the top left cell selected.
Is there any way to fix this? Or should I trace the cell selection manually and update scroll position myself?

Comment: I think you have to do the scrolling yourself, manipulating the div's scrollTop and scrollLeft after comparing the cell's position and size to the size of the div - won't be easy : )

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of.
Hard to believe that such keyboard manipulations don't trigger scrolling events, even though the table itself DOES scroll...

Comment: What do you mean - scrolls in relation to what ?

Comment: In relation to its container div.
I.e., I have a page, on the page there is a fixed size div with the scrollbars, inside which is a very large table. When I use the div's scrollbar, the table scrolls inside this div.
The same with the keyboard navigation: when I use the arrow keys, the table MOVES inside the div (as if I used the scrollbars), but the scrollbars don't update, and the scroll events don't fire.

Comment: That IS strange. Just tried to put a large table inside a small div (overflow:scroll) - if I click inside the div, and then use the arrow-keys it scrolls as expected (and the bars show it, too). Maybe, in your case, the browsers focus() is not in the place you think it is ?

Comment: Looks like I will have to set up a test page to share. Will post here when I do that..